# Use another file for realm queries in React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

Im new to React-Native and Im using Realm as my database. Im trying to create a class which holds all my realm queries and I will use it in my components.
**Today.js** and **Queries.js** are on the same folder. I have this on my Today.js

```
import Queries from './Queries'
componentDidMount() {
   this._isMounted = true;
   let a = Queries.getAllExpenses();
}
```

and this is what I have on my **Queries.js**.

```
import Realm from 'realm'
let realm = new Realm({
schema: 
[
    {
    name: 'Expenses', 
    properties: 
        {
            id: 'int',
            value: 'int', 
            category: 'string', 
            description: 'string', 
            date: 'string', 
        }
    },
    {
    name: 'Categories', 
    properties: 
        { 
            id: 'int',
            name: 'string',
        }
    },
]
})

export default class Queries {
getAllExpenses() {
    let data = realm.objects('Expenses');
    let allExpenses = [];
    let i=0;
    for (; i <= data.length; i++) {
      allExpenses.push(data[i]);
    }
    return allExpenses;
}
getAllCategories() {
    return realm.objects('Categories');
};
}
```

Im getting the error **undefined is not a function (evaluating '_Queries2.default.getAllExpenses()')**
Am I doing this wrong? I would be really glad for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to call the `getAllExpenses` method directly on the class, not on an instance of the class.

You should either change your export statement to instantiate the class: `export default new Queries` (and move the class definition itself above the export statement), or you could mark your methods as `static` if you want to use your class more like a namespace.